# sql query to check minimum 2 records exist

Tags: sql, group-by, count

i have a view like this :

```
select Horse_Name, LevelName, TYPE_NAME, Event_Name, Result_Name
from V_Horse_Transaction
```

my result is like this :

```
Horse_Name    LevelName   TYPE_NAME Result_Name
DXB-HORSE     QUALIFIER    40        PASS
DXB-HORSE     QUALIFIER    40        PASS
DXB-HORSE     QUALIFIER    80        PASS
DXB-HORSE     QUALIFIER    80        PASS
INDIAN-HORSE    QUALIFIER  40        FAIL
DXB-HORSE      QUALIFIER   40        PASS
INDIAN-HORSE    QUALIFIER  40         PASS
INDIAN-HORSE    QUALIFIER  80         FAIL
INDIAN-HORSE    QUALIFIER  80         FAIL
```

In my query I want show only the horse name which is minimum having 2 records of 40 and 2 records of 80 and both result type is “Pass” and LevelName='QUALIFIER'. so i wrote query like this .but i am not getting any records :
my query is like this :

```
select  Horse_Name, COUNT(2)
from V_Horse_Transaction
where TYPE_NAME = 40 and TYPE_NAME = 80
  and Result_Name = 'PASS' and LevelName = 'QUALIFIER' 
group by TYPE_NAME, Result_Name, LevelName, Horse_Name
```

Comment: TYPE_NAME can never be 40 and 80 at the same time.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: If i have records minimum two 40 and minimum two 80 with result type is pass..then only i want to show the records

Comment: `... where TYPE_NAME IN (40, 80) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by Horse_Name` an dset the conditions in the `having` clause:

```
select Horse_Name
from V_Horse_Transaction
where TYPE_NAME in (40, 80) and Result_Name = 'PASS' and LevelName = 'QUALIFIER' 
group by Horse_Name
having count(case when TYPE_NAME = 40 then 1 end) >= 2
   and count(case when TYPE_NAME = 80 then 1 end) >= 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hZmeDcMVQqbkyGfCL9WHcn/0).
Results:

```
| Horse_Name |
| ---------- |
| DXB-HORSE  |
```